# importing CELERY* environment variables in django settings.py causes celeryd not to start

Tags: django-celery

I just spent 2 hours trying to figure out why django celery stopped working.

Celery would being to start, but would stop short of printing out the configuration items, implying that it wasn't starting correct. The log would only contain

`The celery.decorators module along with the magic keyword arguments,
are deprecated, and will be removed in version 3.0.`

Please use the `celery.task` module instead of `celery.decorators`,
and the `task.request` should be used instead of the magic keyword arguments:

```
from celery.task import task
```

See http://bit.ly/celery22major for more information.

"""))

It turns out that some celery env variables that I was importing to try and fix a different problem were causing celery not to start correctly:

```
from celery.tests.config import CELERY_QUEUES, CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE, CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY
```

Even though I wasn't using them anywhere.

Does anyone know what was happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constants I'm importing bring are actually constants defined for celery *tests* (celery.tests.config). When imported, their corresponding values into the scope of settings.py, so when celeryd runs, instead of defaulting to their (correct) respective values, celery ends up using the test CELERY_QUEUES defined in celery.tests.config.